# Dijkstra Problem[UVa-10986 Sending Email]

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

My answer is accept for UVa, but I got 21 wrong in udebug. I am wondering whether I am wrong in my Dijkstra Template.

I first set all the dis to 1e9, when the node was visited, the dis will be update, I don't think there is any wrong, but when I use other people's template of Dijkstra, there is no wrong answer.

The most weird thing is that I was accept by UVa, so I didn't know where is the bug.

https://www.udebug.com/UVa/10986 (input is the user Batman)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n, m ,S, T;
int w[20010][20010], dis[20010];
vector<int> v[20000+10];
struct Node
{
    int node, weight;
    Node(int _n, int _w){
        node = _n;
        weight = _w;
    }   
    bool operator<(Node const other)const{
        return weight > other.weight;
    }
};
void dijsktra(int src)
{
    priority_queue<Node> pq;
    pq.push(Node(src, 0));
    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        auto top = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        if(dis[top.node] != 1e9) continue;
        dis[top.node] = top.weight;
        for(auto i : v[top.node]){
            if(dis[i] == 1e9) pq.push(Node(i, top.weight + w[top.node][i]));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int N, cnt = 1, temp1, temp2, tempw; 
    cin >> N;
    while(N--){
        cin >> n >> m >> S >> T;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            v[i].clear();
            dis[i] = 1e9;
        }

        while(m--)
        {
            cin >> temp1 >> temp2 >> tempw;
            v[temp1].push_back(temp2);
            v[temp2].push_back(temp1);
            w[temp1][temp2] = w[temp2][temp1] = tempw;
        }
        dijsktra(S);
        if(dis[T] != 1e9)   printf("Case #%d: %d\n", cnt++, dis[T]);
        else printf("Case #%d: unreachable\n", cnt++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add a blank line in the output before `return 0;` in `main`? `std::cout << '\n';`

Comment: I think it doesn't work, because the number is wrong not the presentation error.